# SwiftUI: FocusState animations stop working when using NavigationViews

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement an animation relating to a TextField. A Cancel button slide in when the textfield is clicked. However, it only works correctly when it's in a standalone view. When I try to nest the view within a NavigationLink, the animation stops working. Here's the code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @FocusState private var isEditing: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("click me", action: { isEditing.toggle() })

            HStack {
                TextField("Search", text: .constant("test"))
                    .focused($isEditing)
                    .padding(8)
                    .padding(.leading, 25)
                    .padding(.trailing, 22)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                if isEditing {
                    Button {} label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Text("Cancel")
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .padding(.trailing)
                        }
                    }
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: isEditing)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Correct animation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z06Jl.jpg

However, when I have a second view with a NavigationLink containing the previous view:

```
struct TestView2: View {
    @State var test: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(isActive: $test, destination: { TestView() }, label: {})
                Button("click me", action: { test.toggle() })
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

The animation looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbJcp.jpg

Is this a bug related to SwiftUI? Or am I not supposed to use FocusState for animations? If so, how can I change the code to have the animation work in both versions?

Comment: NavigationView has deprecated, so don't spend time on it - it is very very very ... hmmm specific :)

Comment: I’ll have to check new Navigation manager out!

Comment: It is interesting which OS do you use, because on iOS 15.5 I see absolutely different animation in both cases, and both are weird. :)

Comment: they seems to use internally withAnimation on isEditing changing that's why everything is animated and cannot be blocked.

Comment: I'm on iOS 15.5 and I just tried it in a new project and the first version seems to be giving me that bug too now. I have it implemented in another project that I have and the results were the videos I linked. I'm not sure how I can edit the code to have the Cancel button slide in using .transition and .spring without it looking like that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the animations by changing the FocusState variable to a State variable and then removing the .focused modifier and changing it to .onTapGesture, setting the isEditing variable to true